# Using ServiceStack Redis from .net core and connecting to Sentinel setup

Tags: c#, redis, asp.net-core, servicestack.redis

I have created a .net core console application and included the ServiceStack.Redis.Core v1.0.23 nuget package. I also have the redis sentinel setup running locally. When I try to connect to redis using the sentinel connection method the application hangs on sentinel.start(). There are no errors returned.

If I create the same application using a windows console application using a standard windows C# project and including the ServiceStack.Redis v4.5.4 nuget package the same connection code works fine.

I have also managed to connect from an .net core application using a single redis instance, but not using the sentinel.

Has anyone else experienced this or know of a way to get this working inside a .net core application?

Code used to try to connect:

```
var sentinelHosts = new[] { "127.0.0.1:26380", "127.0.0.1:26381", "127.0.0.1:26382" };
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, masterName: "mymaster");

var clientManager = sentinel.Start();
```

Comment: can you share configuration files for your redis/sentinnel hosts?

Comment: I used the setup from https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-config without any changes.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it, let's see what can be done

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, which should be fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/commit/aef445a0e9c07ae01087a2ea62bbe39b0d80d37c). `sentinel.Start()` makes a call to `RedisPubSubServer` which blocks current thread on .NET Core and that is why control does not return back and hangs. This change will be available on nuget with ServiceStack.Redis.Core v1.0.25 package.